# JSTL not printing my passed attribute from servlet. Is scope or not accessing doGet() the issue?

Tags: jsp, servlets, foreach, jstl

I'm making a simple blog application. User enters an announcement, its passed to servlet where it is inserted into a database in the POST method via DAO. The GET method creates an arrayList by retrieving all the data via the same DAO and passing it to the view page. Not sure if I'm not using the right scope? The servlet is inserting announcements into database I know that for sure.

```
package testSource;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/testAnnounceServlet")
 public class testAnnounceServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        AnnouncementDAO dao = new AnnouncementDAO();
        ArrayList<Announcement> announcementList = new ArrayList<>(dao.getAllAnnouncements());

        request.setAttribute("jspList", announcementList);

        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/testPost.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String sentAnnouncement = request.getParameter("announceText"); 

        Announcement announcementForDatabase = new Announcement();
        AnnouncementDAO writeDAO = new AnnouncementDAO();

        if(sentAnnouncement != null)
        {
            announcementForDatabase.setDate();
            announcementForDatabase.setAnnouncement(sentAnnouncement);  

            try {
                    writeDAO.writeAnnouncement(announcementForDatabase);
                    response.sendRedirect("/test/testPost.jsp");
                } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(testAnnounceServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
        }
        else
        {
            response.sendRedirect("/Error.jsp");
        }  
    }    
}
```

This is my DAO

```
package testSource;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class AnnouncementDAO 
{
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/POSTS";
    final String USER = "root";
    final String PASS = "Sorosh1310";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    public void getConnection()
    {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName(driver);
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(AnnouncementDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try 
        {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
        }catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(AnnouncementDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try 
        {
            if(stmt== null)
            {
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(AnnouncementDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }

    public void closeConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            if(stmt!=null)
            conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se)
        {
        }

        try
        {
            if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException se)
        {
        }
    }

    public void writeAnnouncement(Announcement passedAnnouncement)
    throws Exception 
    {
        Announcement dbAnnouncement = passedAnnouncement;

        java.sql.Date sqlDate = dbAnnouncement.getDate();
        String dbText = dbAnnouncement.getAnnouncement();

        String SQL = "INSERT INTO POSTS.ANNOUNCEMENTS (AnnouncementDate, AnnouncementText)"+
        "VALUES (?, ?)";

        getConnection();

        if(stmt != null)
        {
            try
            {
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
                preparedStmt.setDate(1, sqlDate);
                preparedStmt.setString(2, dbText);
                preparedStmt.execute();

            }catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(AnnouncementDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }


    }

    public ArrayList<Announcement> getAllAnnouncements()
    {
        String retrieveSql = "SELECT * FROM POSTS.ANNOUNCEMENTS ORDER BY AnnouncementID";
        ArrayList<Announcement> announcementList = new ArrayList<>();

        getConnection();

        if(stmt != null)
        {
            try
            {
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(retrieveSql);

                while (rs.next())
                {
                    Announcement listItem = new Announcement();
                    listItem.setDate(rs.getDate("AnnouncementDate"));
                    listItem.setAnnouncement(rs.getString("AnnouncementText"));
                    announcementList.add(listItem);
                }
            }catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(AnnouncementDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        closeConnection();

        return announcementList;
    }

 /*    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Announcement mainAnnounce = new Announcement();
        mainAnnounce.setAnnouncement("This is a test from main");
        mainAnnounce.setDate();

        AnnouncementDAO mainDAO = new AnnouncementDAO();

        try 
        {
            mainDAO.writeAnnouncement(mainAnnounce);
        } catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(AnnouncementDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try
        {
            ArrayList<Announcement> mainList = mainDAO.getAllAnnouncements();
            for(Announcement item : mainList)
            {
                out.print("\n"+item.toString());

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }




     }   
 */   

}
```

This is my view page

```
<%@page import="testSource.Announcement"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div> 
        <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/testAnnounceServlet">
            <c:forEach items="${jspList}" var="announcement">
                <p class ="cssStylesParagraph">
                  <c:out value="${announcement.currentTime}"/>
                  <c:out value="${announcement.dbAnnouncement}"/>
                </p>
            </c:forEach>    
        </form>      
    </div>
    <footer>

  </footer><!-- end .footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my bean

```
package testSource;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Announcement 
{
    String dbAnnouncement = "";
    java.sql.Date currentTime = null;

    public String getAnnouncement()
    {
        return dbAnnouncement;
    }

    public java.sql.Date getDate()
    {
        return currentTime;
    }

    public void setDate(java.sql.Date dateToSet)
    {
        this.currentTime = dateToSet;
    }

    public void setDate()
    {
        String dateString = new Date().toString();

        try {
            Date utilDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(dateString);
            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime()); 
            this.currentTime = sqlDate;
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Announcement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public void setAnnouncement(String announcemenToSet)
    {
        this.dbAnnouncement = announcemenToSet;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return currentTime.toString()+":" +"\n"+ dbAnnouncement;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform the GET request on the controller, not on the view. I.e. the URL which you see in browser's address bar must be the servlet URL, not the JSP URL. This way the servlet's `doGet()` will be invoked.

1. First move the `testPost.jsp` file into the `/WEB-INF` folder so that you (nor the enduser) can't make this mistake anymore.
2. Then alter in the servlet code the `forward()` calls as below:

   ```
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/testPost.jsp").forward(request, response);
   ```

   And the `sendRedirect()` calls as below:

   ```
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/testAnnounceServlet");
   ```
3. Finally make sure that you open/link the page by the following URL:

   ```
    http://localhost:8080/test/testAnnounceServlet
   ```

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)